# Finding an upper bound on second largest eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be odd, $P,Q$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0.75&0.25&0&0\cdots 0&0&0 \\
0.25&0.5&0.25&0\cdots 0&0&0 \\
0&0.25&0.5&0.25\cdots 0&0&0 \\
\vdots \\
0&0&0&0\cdots&0.25&0.5&0.25 \\
0&0&0&0\cdots&0&0.25&0.75 \\
\end{bmatrix},
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\cdots 0&0 \\
0&0&1&0\cdots 0&0 \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

i.e. $P$ has entries $0.5$ along the diagonal except for the first, last rows and $0.25$ above and below the main diagonal. $Q$ is a permutation matrix i.e. there is only one $1$ along each row of $Q$ and the position of that $1$ is shifted by two places to the right as we go down one row. So the position of $1$ along the $3^{rd}$ row in $Q$ is two places to the right of $1$ in $2^{nd}$ row i.e. on the $5^{th}$ column.

> I am trying to find an upper bound on second largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ of the matrix $QP$?

$QP$ is not a simple triangular matrix, so I found it hard to setup the characteristic polynomial of $QP$ to estimate $\lambda_2$. Any ideas?

Comment: do you want an estimate on the 2nd largest eigenvalue, or on the SLEM -- 2nd largest eigenvalue modulus? If the latter, try to estimate the 2nd largest singular value of QP, by estimating the 2nd largest eigenvalue of $P$ i.e. $ \lambda_2 ^{(P)} =\vert \lambda_2 \vert^{(P)} =\sigma_2^{(P)}=\sigma_2^{(QP)}\geq \vert \lambda_2 \vert^{(QP)}$ noting that $P$ is a symmetric PD markov chain and PQ is doubly stochastic, we know that in all cases $\sigma_1 = \lambda_1=1$

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks, I see that $\lambda_2^{(P)}=|\lambda_2|^{(P)}$ because $P$ is symmetric. Is $\sigma_2^{(QP)}\geq |\lambda_2|^{(QP)}$ because $QP$ is doubly stochastic?

Comment: There are probably a few different ways to justify this.  But the way I'd think about it is: the singular values of an $n\times n$ matrix always *weakly majorize* the modulus of the eigenvalues.   i.e. with the ordering of $\vert \lambda_1 \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2 \vert  \geq ... \geq \vert \lambda_n \vert$ and $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2\geq ...\geq \sigma_n$, you always have $\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i \geq  \sum_{i=1}^k \vert \lambda_i\vert$ for $1\leq k \leq n$.  Now set $k:=2$ and use the fact that $\lambda_1 = 1=\sigma_1$ (which follows from being doubly stochastic and Perron theory)

Comment: note $\lambda_2^{(P)}=|\lambda_2|^{(P)}$ follows because $P$ is symmetric Positive Definite (proof: Gershgorin Discs with Taussky's extension).  Symmetry alone isn't enough.